# RestTemplate not working with APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED and Request Pojo

Tags: java, resttemplate, media-type

I am using restTemplate to consume a service.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(countryRequest, headers);                  
CountryResponse response = restTemplate.postForObject(countryURL, request, CountryResponse.class);
```

`countryRequest` is a object of a POJO with just a string field `code`. 
`restTemplate` has `jackson2HttpMessageConverter` and `FormHttpMessageConverter` in `messageConverters`.

I am getting the following exception :

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: 
  Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [CountryRequest] and content type [application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
```

But if I use `MultiValueMap` instead of `CountryRequest`, I got the 200 response:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.add(code, "usa");
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity(map, headers);
```

Is there any way to replace the `MultiValueMap` approach here?

Answer (score 2):

There is two main kinds of request serialization: as usual FORM data or as JSON object.
Form Data is simplest and oldest way which sends a simple key-value pairs of strings in POST payload. But when you need to send some object with nested properties or some list or even map then it becomes a problem.
That's why everybody tries to use a JSON format which can be more easily deserialized into POJO object. And this is a de facto standard for modern web.

So in your case for some reason `RestTemplate` tries to serialize the `CountryRequest` but it don't know how to serialize it into FORM data.
Try to replace the `request` with a pojo that you are sending:

```
CountryRequest request = new CountryRequest();                  
CountryResponse response = restTemplate.postForObject(countryURL, request, CountryResponse.class);
```

Then RestTemplate tries to serialize the `CountryRequest` into JSON (which is default behavior).